# How to restrict user in opening multiple Tabs in a browser while performing tasks?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have to restrict users in opening multiple tabs of any browser for security purposes like  bank.
I want user to perform their tasks in single Tabs of browser only.

If they try to open multiple tabs then their user IDs must be forcefully log out.

I don't know how to do this.

Please help me out or provide me some logic s to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the security benefit of this?

Answer (score 0):

First, I have to agree with the other users -- if someone having more than one tab open is a **security** issue, you have problems.  Big problems.

However, if you still really want to do this:

When the user logs in:

```
// Must be a string
var dateTimeStamp = "" +new Date().getTime();

// This one can be seen by all windows/tabs
localStorage.setItem("timeKey", dateTimeStamp);
// This one can only be seen by the current window/tab
sessionStorage.setItem("timeKey", dateTimeStamp);
```

Now, when a page loads, just check to see if those two values match:

```
var localKey = localStorage.getItem("timeKey");
var sessionKey = sessionStorage.getItem("timeKey");

// If there is a key:
if (localKey) {
  if (localKey !== sessionKey) {
    // Handle multiple login here? Redirect to login page?
    // Complain about tab?
  }
}
```

Then, when the user logs out, make sure that you remove both of those keys.

```
localStorage.removeItem("timeKey");
sessionStorage.removeItem("timeKey");
```

**Warning:**

This kind of coding is bit fragile and no doubt there is an edge case I missed.

**Extra Credit**

It is possible to monitor changes to `localStorage` and force all the other pages to log out if someone logs in on a new tab.